# How to create an "alignment" variable from mutual rating variables

Tags: spss, reliability

I want to create an "alignment" variable out of two other variables. Meaning, that if two raters (say manager and employee) rate each other similarly, alignment is high, but if they rate each other differently, alignment is low. I tried looking into IRR measures such as ICC and Cohen's Kappa, but they seem to generate only an overall alignment score. I'm looking to generate one alignment value for each pair of raters rating each other - effectively creating a new alignment variable. How can I accomplish this?

Technically I'm using SPSS, but the most important is for me to understand what generic technique to use.

Comment: In response to your flag, I don't think there's much to say: your question looks fine, but there is often less activity during the weekend. However, you can edit your question by adding more details, if you like, or offer a small amount of your reputation (bounty) to draw attention on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way of doing this would be to subtract one variable from the other:

rating2 - rating2 = alignment_variable

If the scale ranges from 1 through 7, that would create a new variable that ranges from 6 to -6. If we take the absolute of that, the variable would essentially become a "misalignment variable" with high values indicating high misalignment (6 being the maximum misalignment possible, and 0 being total alignment). If we then reverse it, we get an alignment variable where higher values indicate higher levels of alignment:

```
6 -> 0
5 -> 1
4 -> 2
3 -> 3
2 -> 4
1 -> 5
0 -> 6
```

If we add 1 to each value we get it on the same scale as the previous variables, i.e. 1 through 7.